# Syncano Android Social Login with custom class results in error

Tags: android, syncano

Social Login in Syncano doesn't work with custom profile. I use `SocialAuthBackend.FACEBOOK`and pass a token with custom class such as:

```
@SyncanoClass(name = "user_profile")
public class UserProfile extends AbstractUser {
}
```

together as:

```
syncano.loginSocialUser(UserProfile.class, SocialAuthBackend.FACEBOOK, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()).sendAsync(new SyncanoCallback<UserProfile>() {
      //...
});
```

Which result in:

```
IllegalArgumentException: field com.syncano.library.data.AbstractUser.profile has type com.syncano.library.data.Profile, got com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:557)
                                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:119)
                                                                               at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:217)
                                                                               at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:861)
                                                                               at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:826)
                                                                               at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:775)
                                                                               at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:747)
```

Can't fix it or find any sample online using this feature (or docs on this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to declare own user profile you should create 2 class:

1. Implementation of `AbstractUser<T>` (where `T` is your profile class name)
2. Your own class `UserProfile` class with extend `Profile` class (from `syncano package`).

Sample code:

```
    @SyncanoClass(name = "user_profile")
    public class MyUserProfile extends Profile {
        @SyncanoField(name = "avatar")
        public SyncanoFile avatar;
    }

    public class CustomUser extends AbstractUser<MyUserProfile> {
            public CustomUser(String login, String pass) {
                 super(login, pass);
             }
    }
```

**Soon release:**

From version 4.0.6 (not published yet) you don't need anymore @SyncanoClass annotation in profile (optional).